# Azure Data Studio Authentication Error logging into Synapse Serverless Pool

Tags: azure, azure-synapse, azure-data-studio

Am trying to login into **Synapse Serverless** from **Azure Data Studio** with **Azure Active Directory - Universal with MFA Support**, but unable to login throws error on Account selection in browser

"`Unidentified error with azure authentication`"

**Update**: changed to 'Device Authentication' and was able to authenticate myself in browser with User Code, but still Azure Data Studio doesn't recognise :(

Also can successfully login from SSMS (SQL Server Management Studio) with both SQL Login and Azure Active Directory :)

But works fine with login in Azure Storage Explorer

Any clues?

Comment: What is your data studio version? Were you able to log in using SSMS via AAD with MFA support?
When you try to log in from Azure data studio, Were you see the below message on the browser once the credentials are validated? Or are you getting this error straight away? 

Your account was added successfully!
You may now close this page.

Comment: @BhargavaGunnam-MSFT : Version of Data Studio is 1.40.2
Yes, in Data Sudio when you click in on 'add account' it opens web page to select appropriate AD account, once selected it throws this error in browser

Full Details of Data Stuido

Version: 1.40.2 (system setup)
Commit: 661384637db384fe5d4e6224069adbe708580b16
Date: 2022-12-22T22:17:02.658Z
VS Code: 1.67.0
Electron: 17.4.11
Chromium: 98.0.4758.141
Node.js: 16.13.0
V8: 9.8.177.14-electron.0
OS: Windows_NT x64 10.0.19041

Comment: I upgraded my data studio to 1.40.2 and was able to authenticate. You mentioned that you could authenticate using device authentication and log into SSMS and azure storage explorer. This indicates there is no issue with your account. I guess this issue is specific to your data studio.  Would it be possible to uninstall and re-install data studio and see if it helps?